# How do i pass the authenticated user from apache kerberos to tomcat GET reques

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, tomcat9, mod-auth-kerb

I'm using Kerberos Mod with apache to authenticate windows user on our intranet sites which are hosted on Ubuntu servers. The backend that gets the data is tomcat. the site in question make a GET request to https://siteName/user/logMeIn . When I try to get the username from the header it's not there.

I've tried adding 
    RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}
    RequestHeader set X-REMOTE-USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
to the apache virtual host file on separate occasions

apache Virtual host file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
               ServerAdmin [serverAdmin]
               ServerName [SiteName]
               ServerAlias [SiteName]

               DocumentRoot [Directory]

               JkMount /ConferenceSchedulerService/* ConferenceSchedulerServicetomcat

               ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
               CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

               SSLEngine on


               SSLCertificateFile     [CertFilePath]
               SSLCertificateKeyFile [CertKeyFilePath]
               <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
               </FilesMatch>
               <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
               </Directory>


               <Directory "/var/www/schedulemeetingtestcom/html">
                       AuthzSendForbiddenOnFailure On
                       Options None
                       AllowOverride None
                       Order allow,deny
                       Allow from all

                       AuthName "SSO Failed please enter you windows    login"
                       AuthType Kerberos
                       KrbAuthRealms CORP.COMPANYNAME.COM
                       KrbServiceName HTTP/schedulemeetingtest.com
                       #KrbServiceName Any
                       Krb5KeyTab /etc/krb5.keytab
                       KrbMethodK5Passwd off
                       KrbLocalUserMapping on
                       KrbSaveCredentials on
                       SSLRequireSSL
                       Require valid-user

                       RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}
                       #RequestHeader set X-REMOTE-USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
               </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

       </VirtualHost>
```

Java Spring Code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController extends BaseController {

   @Autowired
   ApplicationUserAccessLdapService ldapSrv;

   @Autowired
   private HttpServletRequest request;


   @PostMapping(value="/logMeIn")
   public ResponseEntity<?> auth(
   ){

       request.getHeaderNames().toString();
       Enumeration<String> header = request.getHeaderNames();
       Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       while (header.hasMoreElements()) {
           String key = (String) header.nextElement();
           String value = request.getHeader(key);
           map.put(key, value);
       } 
       try{
              map.put("RemoteUserName", request.getRemoteUser());
       }catch(Exception e){
           map.put("RemoteUserName", "Unknown");
       }
       try{
           map.put("RemoteAddress", request.getRemoteAddr());
       }catch(Exception e){
           map.put("RemoteAddress", "Unknown");
       }
       try{
           map.put("AuthType", request.getAuthType());
       }catch(Exception e){
           map.put("AuthType", "Unknown");
       }
       try{
           map.put("SeverletPath", request.getServletPath());
       }catch(Exception e){
           map.put("SeverletPath", "Unknown");
       }
       try{
           map.put("PrincipalName", request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
       }catch(Exception e){
           map.put("PrincipalName", "Unknown");
       }
       return new ResponseEntity(map,HttpStatus.OK);
   }
 }
```

I'm not getting the username at all and maybe it's because the kerberos mod doesn't pass the username after the initial authentication. But I still need it after
Below is the response from the get request

Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate, br"

Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.9"

AuthType: null

Origin: "https://schedulemeetingtest.riverstonegroup.com"

PrincipalName: "Unknown"

RemoteAddress: "192.168.93.140"

RemoteUserName: null

Sec-Fetch-Mode: "cors"

Sec-Fetch-Site: "same-origin"

SeverletPath: "/user/logMeIn"

accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"

connection: "keep-alive"

content-length: "0"

content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

host: "schedulemeetingtest.riverstonegroup.com"

referer: "https://schedulemeetingtest.riverstonegroup.com/"

user-agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"

What i would like to see is the RemoteUserName show the user not null

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem

in the directory

Directory "/var/www/schedulemeetingtestcom/html"

i changed it to

Location /